# I want to add Shortcut JUST DELETE in java

Tags: java, awt, notepad

[NOTEPAD.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iD06y.jpg)

[NOTEPAD I made.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RqyP.jpg)

How I add MenuShortcut JUST DELETE in line 9? Plz help me....

```
ms[0] = new MenuShortcut(KeyEvent.VK_N);
ms[1] = new MenuShortcut(KeyEvent.VK_O);
ms[2] = new MenuShortcut(KeyEvent.VK_S);
ms[3] = new MenuShortcut(KeyEvent.VK_P);
ms[4] = new MenuShortcut(KeyEvent.VK_Z);
ms[5] = new MenuShortcut(KeyEvent.VK_X);
ms[6] = new MenuShortcut(KeyEvent.VK_C);
ms[7] = new MenuShortcut(KeyEvent.VK_V);
ms[8] = new MenuShortcut(KeyEvent.VK_DELETE);
ms[9] = new MenuShortcut(KeyEvent.VK_F);
ms[10] = new MenuShortcut(KeyEvent.VK_F3);
ms[11] = new MenuShortcut(KeyEvent.VK_H);
ms[12] = new MenuShortcut(KeyEvent.VK_G);
ms[13] = new MenuShortcut(KeyEvent.VK_A);
ms[14] = new MenuShortcut(KeyEvent.VK_F5);
```

Comment: Are you using an IDE (Netbeans)?

Comment: @Peter No, I use eclipse.

Comment: You should add more information on what you are trying to accomplish and the minimum code to replicate your problem (see [here for instructions on that](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). In your case the code should be create a window and create your menu

Comment: @baudsp Oh, sorry. I came here for the first time. I reading this link now. thank you for your kindness!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
menuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(
    java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_S, 
    java.awt.Event.CTRL_MASK));
```

where VK_S is the the key you want and CTRL_MASK is the control key.

There is another option by using

```
menuItem.setMnemonic('F');
```

this will work if you press ALT+F when running your program

for just DELETE use

```
jMenuItem1.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_DELETE, 0));
```

Comment: Also, in netbeans if you double click on the shortcut on the menu (in the design view), a new dialog will pop up and from this you are able to add your shortcut key. However, i don't have any experience with eclipse

Comment: Oh, I want to use DELETE key, not VK_S. Sorry... Can I use accelerator only DELETE key?

Comment: But Thanks to your kindness!! Thank you!

Comment: Just Delete? Not CTRL+DELETE or ALT+DELETE?

Comment: @Diana see the updated answer please

Comment: Yes. Just Delete. Is this a impossible...??

Comment: I edited my answer and I wrote some code for Delete. Did this help you?

Comment: I am using awt, But I am going to change swing! Your answer help me mostly!! thanks!

Comment: Pleased to help :)

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, Shortcut JUST DELETE is enable in awt?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.. However I didn't use awt for like ages...

Comment: Oh, I hear what you are saying. OK, Thank you very much!